# Ruby SQlite SELECT Returning an Unwanted Array

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, select, execute

I am trying to grab a couple values from an sqlite database, but instead of returning the value I am `SELECT`-ing, it is returning that value in an array inside of another array.

---

**My code:**

```
def self.find(id, database_connection)
  name = database_connection.execute("SELECT name FROM pokemon WHERE id = ?", id)
  type = database_connection.execute("SELECT type FROM pokemon WHERE id = ?", id)

  pokemon_inst = Pokemon.new(id: id, name: name, type: type, db: database_connection)
end
```

**The Problem:**

When I run `pry.binding`

`name` outputs `[["Pikachu"]]`

`type` outputs `[["electric]]`

---

Is this working correctly? I can't imagine I should I just be calling `name[0][0]` to access the data, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execute() method wraps everything it is returning in an array, and each database row is placed in an array. So, for the single value being queried to be in two arrays is correct.

Since everything is working as it should I will be adjusting my code to this:

```
def self.find(id, database_connection)
  pokemon = database_connection.execute("SELECT * FROM pokemon WHERE id = ?", id).flatten
  name = pokemon[1]
  type = pokemon[2]

  pokemon_inst = Pokemon.new(id: id, name: name, type: type, db: database_connection)
end
```

The adjustments are to `flatten` the array when it is assigned the queried data and to assign the individual values from that array.

Comment: You can also use exec_query and to_hash to get a key, value paired result.

Comment: That could be also be `name, type = database_connection.execute('SELECT name, type FROM pokemon WHERE id = ?', id).flatten`. And note in Rails type is a reserved word.

Comment: Good to know about type being off limits.